# Is it possible to connect a documentDB store to my app using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I don't see an SDK for JavaScript. As well, there doesn't seem to be a way connect my app service to a documentDB store via the Azure portal. The only options I see are for SQL Database or Storage.

I have a Cordova app that I need an mBaaS for and Azure App Services w/documentDB looks like a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentDB provides both a vanilla JS and Node.js SDK, both can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-introduction).